# JS - Hover on parent, exclude child

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I would like to make a cursor visible when the mouse hovers over a div excluding its child.

Here is what I did:

**HTML**

```
<section id="modal-root">
  <div class="modal">
     <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.cursor {
  position: fixed;
  top: calc(50vh - 50px);
  left: calc(50vw - 50px);
  cursor: none;
  content: url(../cursor.gif);
  width: 1.8%;
  z-index: 5000!important;
  opacity:0;
}


.cursor-visible {
  opacity:1;
}
```

**JS**

```
window.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event){
    $(".cursor")[0].style.top = (event.clientY + 15) + "px";
    $(".cursor")[0].style.left = (event.clientX + 15) + "px";
  })


$("#modal-root:not(.modal)").hover(
  function() {
    $(".cursor").addClass("cursor-visible");
  }, function() {
    $(".cursor").removeClass("cursor-visible");
  }
);
```

**It works but it does not exclude the child. Could you tell me where I went wrong ?**

Comment: Why are you adding the classes with Javascript? In CSS you can usually use `:hover` to achieve the same effect, is there a reason why your code doesn't do this?

Comment: `#modal-root:not(.modal)` - your element with the ID `modal-root` does not have the class `modal` - so while this will select the element, it is also rather redundant.

Comment: Hovering an element, also automatically means hovering all of its ancestors, up to the root element. The only way to prevent that, would be to make the child not react to pointer events at all (`pointer-events: none`) - but that might easily collide with the rest of the functionality, if the user actually needs to interact with it in some other form. Checking the original event target might help.

Comment: @Luke
I can't go through CSS because I want an image that is added to my cursor and not a change of cursor

Comment: @CBroe
Could you tell me more? How would you do? I did that but it doesn't work...

Comment: @Mackgregor fair enough... but you can change the cursor through CSS too! See here for a bit more info https://css-tricks.com/using-css-cursors/

Comment: `.addClass("cursor-visible")` *is* changing through css - just you're adding the class via js instead of using css rules to do it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

As said before, I think you don't need the Javascript and can solve this through CSS.

Try:

```
#modal-root{
  cursor: url('../cursor.gif');
}

#modal-root .modal{
  cursor: default
}
```